# How to make Renderscript update a pointer to struct?

Tags: java, android, pointers, struct, renderscript

So I have this struct with a pointer in Renderscript code:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(4))) RGB {
    float red;
    float green;
    float blue;
} RGB_t;

RGB_t *rgb;
```

This is how I'm allocating and binding memory to this pointer:

```
ScriptField_RGB rgbs = new ScriptField_RGB(mRS, bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight());
function_script.bind_rgb(rgbs);
```

This is how I set my initial values:

```
int index = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); ++y) {
    for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); ++x) {
       int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
       ScriptField_RGB.Item i = new ScriptField_RGB.Item();
       i.red = Color.red(color) / 255.0f;
       i.green = Color.green(color) / 255.0f;
       i.blue = Color.blue(color) / 255.0f;
       rgbs.set(i, index, false);
       index++;
   }
}

rgbs.copyAll();
```

'function_script' is a script with a kernel to populate 'RGB_t*', it's exactly like that:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(my.package)

#include "rgb.rs"

void __attribute__((kernel)) root(RGB_t pixel, uint32_t x) {
    //rsDebug("before", rgb[x].red,rgb[x].green,rgb[x].blue);
    rgb[x].red = pixel.red * 255.0f;
    rgb[x].green = pixel.green * 255.0f;
    rgb[x].blue = pixel.blue * 255.0f;
    //rsDebug("after", rgb[x].red,rgb[x].green,rgb[x].blue);
}
```

Running this kernel with:

```
function_script.forEach_root(arrayOperational);
```

doesn't update my ScriptField values at Android Layer. I still have the old values that I've settled before.

So if I call:

```
rgbs.get(index)
```

I'll get exactly my old value, running after 'foreach root' call, of course.

How can I reflect my changes in the Android Layer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with `Bitmap` like data (RGB values), you should consider using input and output `Allocation` objects rather than your own bindings.  Rendescript will efficiently handle that for you rather than having to manually bind fields like this.

However, if you must do this binding, you'll need to setup the usage of the field to include `Allocation.USAGE_SHARED` (use a different, overloaded constructor.)  With that in place, you should be able to call `updateAllocation()` on the field object in Java to get the latest data from the script.  If that doesn't work (it depends on the auto-generated code), you could try calling `getAllocation()` then calling `Allocation.syncAll(Allocation.USAGE_SHARED)` to get the `Allocation` updated with any changes from the script.  At that point your field access methods should give the updated values.

Comment: Thanks Larry! 

So, that's a good start. I'm using RGB like that just for testing, probably gonna have more complex structs like {int,float, char,...} in the future. Now I'm using this constructor:

`ScriptField_RGB rgbs = new ScriptField_RGB(mRS, bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight(), Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);`

And `rgbs.updateAllocation()` after running all kernels. It didn't work.
So I've tried:

`rgbs.updateAllocation();`
`rgbs.getAllocation().syncAll(Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);`

And now I'm getting NullPointerException. 

Any hints what it could be?

Comment: Hmmm...offhand, no. The base implementation of `updateAllocation()` is a no-op. You might try passing `USAGE_SHARED | USAGE_SCRIPT` to see if it changes; I doubt it will, though. My hope was that the shared usage would cause it to do something.

Comment: Another option you could look at, which would be better IMHO, would be to create a custom `Type` and an `Allocation` of that type then set a field in the RS which is an `Allocation` rather than a pointer.

Comment: Well this could be another option, but, how will I copy back from Renderscript using an Allocation? It only has `copyTo` methods using primitive types.

Basically using this solution, right?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418416/returning-a-renderscript-struct-from-a-renderscript-kernel

Comment: Correct.  You can only copy to/from using primitives.